# Custom Download folder for chromedriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I want to save the files I get with a scraper into custom folders. I looked around and none of the solutions I found worked for me. Here is my configuration:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
        'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
        'download.default_directory': my_data_folder,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled":False,
        }
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222') 
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

desired_caps = {
        'prefs': {
            'savefile': {
                'default_directory': my_data_folder,
                "directory_upgrade": True,
                "extensions_to_open": ""
            }
        }
    }


options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=desired_caps)
```

But when I try downloading, it goes to `~/Downloads/` instead of `my_data_folder`.
I have tried prefs and desired_caps independently to no avail.

I am using Chromium 108.0.5359.22 snap

Help is appreciated !

I have tried:
[How to download to a specific folder with Chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526331/how-to-download-to-a-specific-folder-with-chromedriver)

[Define download directory for chromedriver selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328801/define-download-directory-for-chromedriver-selenium-with-python)

and many other posts and blogs. All these solutions are summarised in the script above.

Thanks !

**UPDATE**
It works if I add

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

The folder option works, but this is not desirable for other reasons. Is there a better way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using `shutil` to move the file after the download ?

Here's how I had that implemented in another project I was working on

```
filename = max([
    download_folder + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(download_folder)],
    key=os.path.getctime)

shutil.move(
    filename,
    os.path.join(download_folder,f"filename.format")
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice workaround, but I would like to set the folder as intended above. There are other reasons why this is desired.